# Cross Platform Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption

Tags: c#, android, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

I have created a self-signed certificate in c#, with a private key created with a `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, 1024 bytes.

I have encrypted a byte array with the public key.

I have then imported the certificate in an Android device.

I try to decrypt my byte array in Android using my certificate private key. My code in Android:

```
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedByte);
}
```

On the last line I get this error: `"java.lang.IllegalStateException"`.

Here are the exception details:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException java.math.BigInteger.remainder(BigInteger.java:919) com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSACoreEngine.processBlock(RSACoreEn‌​gine.java:181)
com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.RSABlindedEngine.processBlock(RSABli‌​ndedEngine.java:109)
com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFi‌​nal(CipherSpi.java:472)
javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1111)
all4r.and.dc.Document.decrypt(Document.java:65)
all4r.and.dc.Decrypt$3$1.onSelection(Decrypt.java:101)
all4r.and.utils.Certificate$1.alias(Certificate.java:42)
android.security.KeyChain$AliasResponse.alias(KeyChain.java:284)
android.security.IKeyChainAliasCallback$Stub.onTransact(IKeyChainAliasCallback.j‌​ava:55)
android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any idea on what the cause of the error is? I've been searching for hours, but haven't found the problem yet.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error? I'm quite sure the exception says more things than it's type. Please edit the message to include the full exception message.

Comment: In asymmetric encryption don't you encrypt with the other side's public key? So shouldn't you encrypt with a public key that the device  has so that it can decrypt the encrypted data with it's private key. How are you getting at the key for the certificate that you imported on the android device?

Comment: QuentinSwain Yes, I encrypt with the public key (sorry, i corrected my question).  To get the private key, I use  KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(activity, new KeyChainAliasCallback() {
 @Override
 public void alias(String alias) {  privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(context, alias);

Comment: @fpilloud dude, don't put details here in the comments. Edit your question to include them there.

Comment: @Renan Sorry. First time I wrote a question. I will take care. Thanks